# input type=date in iOS 7

Tags: date, input, safari, ios7

I have developed a mobile web application and I noticed a change concerning iOS 7, specifically:

- If a web page form contains an input tag of type=date, and the value of the date field is empty (no date value), then the field is rendered in a strange way in Safari, so that the height of the text box is very small (approximately 25% of the height of a normal input type=text box).  Once a date is entered into the control, then the height of the text box is the same as a type=text box.

This did not happen in iOS 6 but is happening in iOS 7. The problem is that it does not look good to me to see these date input boxes rendered in this way.  I would prefer that they look the same as a normal type=text box even when empty.

- Is there anything I can do to get that to happen?
- Is there some initial value I can pass to the type=date text boxes to make them render as they always have?

Thanks in advance.

**updated with screenshots:**

good: [image]

bad: [image]

(that white box should be taller and showing placeholder text)

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of it so we can better understand what you are talking about?

Comment: I am experiencing this exact issue on one of our sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested above, the solution is to manually set the height of the input type=date html control.  A height of 20px for me makes it appear to be the same as the other controls on the page and it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same bug on one of my websites. After investigating it looks like the bug happens on iOS7 when the CSS property `background-color` is set to `transparent`. Empty date inputs height and width are then shrinked.

So it looks like we either have to remove `background-color: transparent` or manually set the height and width of date inputs :(

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the complete case, because our textbox has a solid white background (not transparent) and it's still "collapsing"

Answer (score 0):

The other answer (involving background-color) might be correct for their circumstances, but for us, that didn't fix the issue. We ended up having to specify a height for the input. That did the trick. Definitely an annoying bug.