# on ios7, <input type=date> is not shown in webview without default value

Tags: iphone, ios, html, ios7

I use a UIWebview to display a html page. In the page, I has a date and time type, not datetime.
But the field is not shown on ios7. It's ok on ios6.
below is the css code:

```
div.answer-time-picker {
        padding: 10px 9px;
    }

    .answer-time-picker input {
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: normal;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        border: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

Is there anything wrong?

Thanks a lot!

update:
I found that, if there is a default value, it will work fine.
But if there is no value, it will not show the empty field.
How can I enforce it to display the empty filed for user to click on it?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this input type was removed in iOS 7

http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review

> Following Google Chrome, now Safari on iOS doesn’t support the
>   datetime input type anymore and it will fallback to text. This type
>   was deprecated in the standard in favor of using two inputs, date and
>   time for the same purpose. The problem is that datetime was compatible
>   with iOS from version 5.0 to 6.1; if you are using it, be careful!

Comment: Hi Coline, I also noticed this article, but I think it says "input type=datetime", not the separated date and time.

Answer (score 1):

See the reference [here](http://demo.hongkiat.com/html5-form-input-type/index1.html)

Your CSS should be change as below:

```
{ 
align-items: center;
display: -webkit-inline-flex; 
overflow: hidden; 
padding: 0px; 
-webkit-padding-start: 1px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got some ideas from this quesiton:[input type=date in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967852/input-type-date-in-ios-7)

I set a height in .answer-time-picker input. and it works!