# MDateBox not working on iOS7

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, mgwt

MDateBox not working on iOS7 when you try the Showcase example: http://mobilegwt.appspot.com/showcase/

See the screenshot of the showcase element section. The date box is not rendered. Is there any fix for that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a Bug in iOS7.

You can set the height, as mentioned in this question: [input type=date in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967852/input-type-date-in-ios-7)